# Clarification regarding assert.h header file in C

Tags: c, header-files

I am working with some open source code in C that uses the assert.h header file

```
#include <assert.h>
```

I think I know what assert is used for and why it is in the program, i.e. it is a macro used for debugging purposes which tests some condition and will possibly abort the program if the condition is not met.

My question: there is no `assert.h` header file found within the code proper. This confuses me. 
Is `assert.h` a universal header file, or is this uniquely written for each program?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h

Comment: It is part of the C standard library per section 7.2 - Diagnostics, of the standard (C11).

Comment: `assert.h` it is among the headers specified by the C standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assert.h` (or `cassert` in C++) are in the standard library, similar to `<math.h>` or `<stdlib.h>`. These header files are supplied by the compiler and are automatically in your include path.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library

Comment: Oh, it is in the standard library! Thanks